docker-compose load metadata error for liberica-runtime-container:jdk-17-glibc
I'm running a React.js project using Docker Desktop on an Apple M1 Macbook Air, and the project seemed to compile just fine last week, but recently I've stumbled into the following error:
❯ docker-compose up --build --watch
[+] Building 1.1s (2/2) FINISHED 
docker:desktop-linux=> [backend internal] load build definition from build-backend
=> => transferring dockerfile: 166B 
=> ERROR [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/bellsoft/liberica-runtime-container:jdk-17-glibc 1.0s
------
> [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/bellsoft/liberica-runtime-container:jdk-17-glibc:------
failed to solve: bellsoft/liberica-runtime-container:jdk-17-glibc: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/bellsoft/liberica-runtime-container:jdk-17-glibc: no match for platform in manifest: not found

I cannot seem to find anything online regarding this error.
Things I've Tried

Deleting the config file and recompiling
Completely reinstalling Docker, Java and completely recloning the repository
Toggling the 'containerd' setting in Docker Desktop
Changing 'credsStore' to 'credStore' in config file and recompiling
Running docker login and logging in through Docker
Running export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64, which technically fixed the problem but threw an error with postgresql 16, which said "expected linux/arm64, actual linux/amd64"
docker system prune and docker-compose build backend --no-cache
Self-Diagnosis tool shows no major faults

I'm completely lost, so some help would be greatly appreciated.
